# gitea server is running. and made a test organization there. When I try to do a get request to see the list of organizations, i get a 404 error

Tags: http, get, insomnia, gitea

As mentioned in the title.
I have a gitea server running and have made a test organisation on it.
I am then doing a get request which would list all the organisations, But I get a 400 page not found error.
The pictures below show

1. The gitea server with the organization.
   [image]
2. the scrrenshot of the app that I am using to do the request[image]